# Is there a Visual Studio feature similar to "Code Fragment mode" in IntelliJ?

Tags: visual-studio-2015

"Code Fragment mode" in IntelliJ allows you write arbitrary blocks of code and get the result (if one exists).

I don't see equivalent functionality in Visual Studio.  The Immediate Window doesn't provide as much flexibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In VS2015 there are C# and F# Interactive tool windows.  Each of these provides a REPL (Read-Eval-Print Loop) environment for their respective languages.

[image: Example of C# REPL]

I'm not familiar with the IntelliJ feature, but this sounds like it might be similar?

Comment: That's it!  You rule.